# How to remove dash (-) from string excluding a number from input alphanumeric string in Java

Tags: java, string

I have a String in Java:

```
Hello-World. My phone number is 333-333-333
```

I want to remove dash characters occurring between string but not the digits like as in phone number. My expected output is:

```
Hello World. My phone number is 333-333-333
```

Comment: What would be the desired result of "`333-aaa-333`"?

Comment: Desired result for `333-aaa-333` should be `333 aaa 333`.

Comment: Why does the desired output still contains dashes in between?

Comment: @Frakcool Because they're between digits.

Comment: The dashes should not be removed those in between the numbers. As in phone number.

Comment: Ah! I didn't saw the *"Hello-World"* part was different... I think I'm needing glasses now... @shmosel thanks for clarifying

Comment: What about `333-`?

Comment: 333- should get processed to 333.

Comment: And what about `333-333-aaa`? And `aaa-333-333`?

Comment: for my case, we can safely assume that strings like aaa-333-333 333-333-aaa are invalid. They won't occur.

Comment: So only when there are 3 groups of 3 numbers separated by a dash each, then only in those cases the dashes should remain?

Comment: Yes. That's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fragment that will also handle the other dashes.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printFormattedText("-Hello-World. My 123-phone number-456 is 333-333-333");
        printFormattedText("-123 Hello-World. My 123-phone number-456 is 333-aaa-333-");
    }

    private static void printFormattedText(String input) {
        String result = input.replaceAll("^\\-|(\\D)\\-|\\-(\\D)|\\-$", "$1 $2");
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
 Hello World. My 123 phone number 456 is 333-333-333
 123 Hello World. My 123 phone number 456 is 333 aaa 333
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex`:

```
\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}
```

I did a test in an [online regex tester](http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyEwsSBlJlY2lwZRiAgICgnpSDCQw/index.html) and got this result:

[image]

As you can see, it only matched 2 of them, the ones with 3 groups of 3 digits only. Now use that to replace the dash characher `-` everywhere where this `regex` doesn't match and you're done.

Comment: If this solves your question, be sure to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Frakcook is correct. 
For the specific use case, where my input string is either dashes between number of string-string, following regex worked for me:

```
myString.replaceAll("([A-Za-z])(-)([A-Za-z])", "$1 $3")
```